# Need Assistance! Tweaking iteration(Looping) through multiple columns in SQLITE3 PYTHON

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, iteration, multiple-columns

I have the following code below:  It iterates through three columns grabbing the date from the Date (Column), high value from Vix_High (Column), Low value from Vix_Low(column). When the next value is lower or higher it replaces them until the difference between the values is >0.16 then it saves these values and the associated dates in a new table. This part all works. And I am happy I have been able to get this far as I am new to Python.

I have one issue that needs tweaking and I feels stuck.
The code iterates through about 5000 rows through these three columns starting at the latest date back in 2013. I need it so that the high value that is saved is atleast 1 day after the low value, it could be more but it can't be before.

example:  2014-01-02 13.24  2014-01-15 18.69  -  Correct

example:  2015-03-25 12.11  2015-03-08 17.55 -  Incorrect

Right now my program has both. I need it so Once the local Low value is found - only then can the high value start to be found following that date. When the difference between the two is >0.16  it can deposit the data and then start where it left off - finding the low value and then finding the local high value.
Any Suggestions?

```
import sqlite3
import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('VIX.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VIX_ANALYSIS (LLDate integer, Lower_Limit real, ULDATE integer, Upper_Limit real)')
conn.commit()
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(Date) FROM VIX")
row_count=cur.fetchone()[0]
print (row_count)
#lowhigh_list=[]

def vix_analysis():
    high=1.3
    low=99.9
    index=0
    while index < row_count:
        cur.execute("SELECT Date FROM VIX")
        local_date=cur.fetchall()[index]
        cur.execute("SELECT Vix_Low FROM VIX")
        local_low=cur.fetchall()[index]
        cur.execute("SELECT Vix_High FROM VIX")
        local_high=cur.fetchall()[index+1]
        cur.execute("SELECT Date FROM VIX")
        local_hdate=cur.fetchall()[index+1]
        print (local_date, local_high, local_low)

        if local_low[0] <= low:
            low = local_low[0]
            date_low=local_date[0]
        else:
            low=low

        if local_high[0] >= high:
            high = local_high[0]
            date_high=local_hdate[0]
        else:
            high=high

            if 8 <= low <= 10 and (high - low)/low >= 0.31:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO VIX_ANALYSIS(LLDate, Lower_Limit, ULDATE, Upper_Limit) Values(?,?,?,?)',(date_low, low, date_high, high))
                conn.commit()
                high=1.3
                low=99.9
            elif 10 < low <= 12 and (high - low)/low >= 0.26:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO VIX_ANALYSIS(LLDate, Lower_Limit, ULDATE, Upper_Limit) Values(?,?,?,?)',(date_low, low, date_high, high))
                conn.commit()
                high=1.3
                low=99.9
            elif 12 < low <= 16 and (high - low)/low >= 0.23:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO VIX_ANALYSIS(LLDate, Lower_Limit, ULDATE, Upper_Limit) Values(?,?,?,?)',(date_low, low, date_high, high))
                conn.commit()
                high=1.3
                low=99.9
            elif 16 < low <= 19 and (high - low)/low >= 0.19:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO VIX_ANALYSIS(LLDate, Lower_Limit, ULDATE, Upper_Limit) Values(?,?,?,?)',(date_low, low, date_high, high))
                conn.commit()
                high=1.3
                low=99.9
            elif low > 19 and (high - low)/low >= 0.16:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO VIX_ANALYSIS(LLDate, Lower_Limit, ULDATE, Upper_Limit) Values(?,?,?,?)',(low, date_low, high, date_high))
                conn.commit()
                high=1.3
                low=99.9
            else:
                low=low
                high=high
            

        print (high, date_high, low, date_low)
        index+=1
    
vix_analysis()
```

Comment: Add a flag that tells you if you're looking for a low or a high

Comment: What is a Flag?

Comment: A variable that you can check. I would use a bool, but you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Would you be able to give a small example? I have been using python for 10 days so half these words are french to me. I'll google and readup on flags and bools too.

Comment: flag (or bool variable) is `seach_low = True` / `seach_low = False` and you use it to control what code to execute `if search_low: ... else: ...`

Comment: So essentially nested if statements ?